# Extracting multiple values with RegEx in a Google Sheet formula

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google spreadsheet with 2 columns.

Each cell of the first one contains JSON data, like this:

```
{
    "name":"Love",
    "age":56
},
{
    "name":"You",
    "age":42
}
```

Then I want a second column that would, using a formula, extract every value of name and string it like this:

```
Love,You
```

Right now I am using this formula:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, CONCATENER(CHAR(34),"name",CHAR(34),":",CHAR(34),"([^",CHAR(34),"]+)",CHAR(34),","))
```

The RegEx expresion being `"name":"([^"]+)",`

The problem being that it currently only returns the first occurence, like this:

```
Love
```

(Also, I don't know how many occurences of "name" there are. Could be anywhere from 0 to around 20.)

Is it even possible to achieve what I want?

Thank you so much for reading!

**EDIT:**

My JSON data starts with:

```
{
   "time":4,
   "annotations":[
      {
```

Then in the middle, something like this:

```
{
    "name":"Love",
    "age":56
},
{
    "name":"You",
    "age":42
}
```

and ends with:

```
],
   "topEntities":[
      {
         "id":247120,
         "score":0.12561166,
         "uri":"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revenue"

},
      {
         "id":31512491,
         "score":0.12504959,
         "uri":"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wii_U"

}

],
   "lang":"en",
   "langConfidence":1.0,
   "timestamp":"2020-05-22T12:17:47.380"
}
```

Comment: You may do something like `=REGEXEXTRACT(C1, "(?s)""name"":""([^""]+)""(?:.*?""name"":""([^""]+)"")?")` and just keep adding optional `(?:.*?""name"":""([^""]+)"")?` at the end to find more matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your text is basically a JSON string, you may parse all `name` fields from it using the following custom function:

```
function ExtractNamesFromJSON(input) {
  var obj = JSON.parse("[" + input + "]");
  var results = obj.map((x) => x["name"])
  return results.join(",")
}
```

Then use it as `=ExtractNamesFromJSON(C1)`.

If you need a regex, use a similar approach:

```
function ExtractAllRegex(input, pattern,groupId,separator) {
  return Array.from(input.matchAll(new RegExp(pattern,'g')), x=>x[groupId]).join(separator);
}
```

Then use it as `=ExtractAllRegex(C1, """name"":""([^""]+)""",1,",")`.

Note:

- `input` - current cell value
- `pattern` - regex pattern
- `groupId` -  Capturing group ID you want to extract
- `separator` - text used to join the matched results.

[image]

Comment: That's SO freaking AWESOME! Both solutions work, but the second one using regex works best for my particular case. Thank you SO much for going out of your way to help me! <3