# how to extract all email addresses from a user inputted list in Google Sheets with REGEXEXTRACT

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a user input with a list of email addresses. They separator could be anything like a space, comma, semicolon, tab, new line, multiple separators, etc...

I'm trying to "sanitize" the input and product just a comma separated list of valid email addresses.

This is the regular expression I am using for a valid e-mail address: `([a-z0-9'_.-]+?@[a-z0-9_.-]+?\.[a-z]{2,3})`

This is some sample input:

```
aaa@bbb.com ccc@ddd.ef, ggg@hhh.ij       ;;;;**a23asdf =_ kkkkkk@llll.com
:
:;,
       mmmm@nnn.op"
```

`REGEXEXTRACT` only extracts the first match.

[image]

How can I get it to extract all of the found matches?

I have seen online tricks saying to have two `REGEXEXTRACT` calls, one to replace the matches, then another to replace whats left. While that works, I am wondering if its possible to get `REGEXEXTRACT` to extract all matches. Like a global modifier for the regex.

Comment: Can you use a user-defined function? It will be very easy then. `function ExtractAllRegex(input, pattern,groupId,separator) {
  return Array.from(input.matchAll(new RegExp(pattern,'g')), x=>x[groupId]).join(separator);
}`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61955316/extracting-multiple-values-with-regex-in-a-google-sheet-formula/61956119#61956119).

Comment: @user13469682 How is this a duplicate? My question is specific to doing this in Google Sheets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's going to be relatively tough through `REGEXEXTRACT` since it won't support global modifier. But some alternative could be (still using your pattern):

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"([a-z0-9'_.-]+?@[a-z0-9_.-]+?\.[a-z]{2,3})","|$1|"),"|")),"Select Col1 where Col1 like '%@%'"))
```

Or a little simpler:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(", ",1,IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(A1," "),"([a-z0-9'_.-]+?@[a-z0-9_.-]+?\.[a-z]{2,3})"),"")))
```

Just be aware that the `REGEXREPLACE` now uses `|` which you might need to change depending on what characters may or may not occur.

Comment: Nice use of `IFERROR` and `TEXTJOIN` to eliminate output for the substrings that don't match.  Simpler formula than mine.  And you could just add another `SPLIT` and `TRANSPOSE` if he wanted the output in separate cells.

Comment: The first one works even if email addresses are not separated by spaces. Thanks!

Comment: I modified yours to end up with this: `=JOIN(", ", REGEXEXTRACT(A1, REGEXREPLACE(A1, "([a-z0-9'_.-]+?@[a-z0-9_.-]+?\.[a-z]{2,3})", "($1)")))`. Find all matches of an email address, replace them with `(...)` and then use that as the regular expression to extract from original input.

Comment: Doh. Sorry. Thought I did that last night.

Answer (score 3):

Please try:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1;"\Q"&REGEXREPLACE(A1;"\w\S*@\S+\w";"\\E(.*)\\Q")&"\E")
```

Reference:

https://github.com/google/re2/blob/main/doc/syntax.txt

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
=transpose(arrayformula(filter(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(A1," "),"([a-z0-9'_.-]+?@[a-z0-9_.-]+?\.[a-z]{2,3})"),not(isna(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(A1," "),"([a-z0-9'_.-]+?@[a-z0-9_.-]+?\.[a-z]{2,3})"))))))
```

- Split the string into an array on spaces
- Use your regex to validate each array member
- Filter out the non-matching members
- Use `arrayformula` to return all of the matching members
- Transpose to return a vertical array

[image]