# How do I extract the nth occurence of a regex match from a string?

Tags: regex, spreadsheet

I have a string in one cell of a Google sheet from which I wish to extract image filenames into separate cells in the sheet to isolate the filenames from the string. For instance ...

[image]

So, if the original string was ...

`{[file_name_1.png][yes]}{[file_name_2.jpg][no]}{[file_name_3.png][no]}`

... then I'd like the three following cells to have `file_name_1.png`, `file_name_2.jpg`, `file_name_3.png` in them.

I've tried the following ...

`(.*?[A-Za-z0-9_]+\.(?:(?:png)|(?:jpg))){1}` which gives `{[file_name_1.png`

`(.*?[A-Za-z0-9_]+\.(?:(?:png)|(?:jpg))){2}` which gives `][yes]}{[file_name_2.jpg`

`(.*?[A-Za-z0-9_]+\.(?:(?:png)|(?:jpg))){3}` which gives `][no]}{[file_name_3.png`

... so I feel like I'm nearly there. Could someone please help me understand where i'm going wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use three capturing groups separated with `.*?` pattern that matches any 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "([A-Za-z0-9_]+\.(?:png|jpg)).*?([A-Za-z0-9_]+\.(?:png|jpg)).*?([A-Za-z0-9_]+\.(?:png|jpg))")
```

[image]

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hIlLNT/1).

**Details**

- `([A-Za-z0-9_]+\.(?:png|jpg))` - a capturing group matching 1 or more letters, digits or underscores, `.`, and then either `png` or `jpg`
- `.*?` - matches 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible.

If the second and third file names are optional, wrap the `.*?` and the file pattern with an optional non-capturing group:

```
"([A-Za-z0-9_]+\.(?:png|jpg))(?:.*?([A-Za-z0-9_]+\.(?:png|jpg)))?(?:.*?([A-Za-z0-9_]+\.(?:png|jpg)))?"
```

**Recap**

To get the first match, just use

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "[A-Za-z0-9_]+\.(?:png|jpg)")
```

To get the second, use

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "(?:.*?([A-Za-z0-9_]+\.(?:png|jpg))){2}")
```

To get the third, use

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "(?:.*?([A-Za-z0-9_]+\.(?:png|jpg))){3}")
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response :) This seems to work well. However, how can I extract *just* the first, second and third individually? Basically, I want to make the filename for each image into a hyperlink.

Comment: So, to extract the first one, I've made the second and third non-capturing groups by adding ?: inside the first group. To extract the second one, added ?: inside the second group and the same for the third.


```=REGEXEXTRACT($A5, "([A-Za-z0-9_]+\.(?:png|jpg)).*?(?:[A-Za-z0-9_]+\.(?:png|jpg)).*?(?:[A-Za-z0-9_]+\.(?:png|jpg))")```


This does seem a little long winded - is there a quicker / simpler way?

Comment: @MrMills There is a way to simplify it greatly only with custom user function written in JavaScript. See an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61956119/3832970).

Comment: Ah @wiktor - you've answered my question :) Thank you!